# JS: why do i need brackets to call a method on number?

Tags: javascript, methods, prototypal-inheritance

```
function func2method(f){
    return function(y) {
        return f(this, y);
    };
}

Number.prototype.add = func2method(function(x, y){return x+y});
```

Why do I have to use brackets to call this method on a number?

For example, `3.add(4)` won't work while `(3).add(4)` works perfectly fine.

Comment: It's because it's getting mixed up with numeric grammar. `3.` is a valid number literal.

Comment: Yeah, as MinusFour says, your intentions are ambiguous with `3.add(4)`.

Comment: Fun fact: you *can* do `3..add(4)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `3.0` is not the same as `(3)['0']`

Literals are interpreted differently. The point `.` represents a decimal point on a numeric literal, but the point `.` on an object represents a property accessor (translated to square bracket notation above)